# Método POST no Controller ASP.NET API está auto-incrementando chave estrangeira mesmo que o valor deva ser vazio

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, http-request, auto-incremento

Possuo o seguinte código:

```
public ActionResult Post(Project project)
  {
    try
      {            
         _acess.AddProject(project);
      }
    catch(DataException ex)
      {
         BadRequest(ex.Message);
      }
      return Ok();
  }
```

Objeto JSON enviado:

```
{
  "Id": 0,
  "Name": "string",
  "Image": "string",
  "Why": "string",
  "What": "string",
  "WhatWillWeDo": "string",
  "ProjStatus": 0,
  "Course": {
    "CourseId": 0,
    "Name": "string"
  },
  "CourseId": 0
}
```

Classe Project:

```
public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nome é obrigatório")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Why { get; set; }
    public string What { get; set; }
    public string WhatWillWeDo { get; set; }
    public ProjectStatus ProjStatus { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }

    public int CourseId { get; set; }

    public enum ProjectStatus
    {
        development = 0,
        publicated = 1
    }
}
```

Classe Course

```
public class Course
{
    [Key]
    public int CourseId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Classe de contexo

```
    public class StreamerContext : DbContext
    {
        public StreamerContext(DbContextOptions<StreamerContext> option) : base(option) {}

        public StreamerContext() : base()
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Course> Course { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Project> Project { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=SS_DB.db");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().ToTable("Project");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().HasKey(pre => pre.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().Property(pre => pre.Id).HasColumnName("id");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().Property(pre => pre.Name).HasColumnName("name");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().Property(pre => pre.Image).HasColumnName("image");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().Property(pre => pre.Why).HasColumnName("why");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().Property(pre => pre.What).HasColumnName("what");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().Property(pre => pre.WhatWillWeDo).HasColumnName("whatWillWeDo");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().Property(pre => pre.ProjStatus).HasColumnName("projStatus");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().Property(pre => pre.CourseId).HasColumnName("courseId");

            modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().ToTable("Course");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().HasKey(pre => pre.CourseId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().Property(pre => pre.CourseId).HasColumnName("id");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().Property(pre => pre.Name).HasColumnName("name");
        }
    }
}
```

Método de Adicionar

```
public void AddProject(Project item)
  {
    context.Project.Add(item);
    Save();          
 }
```

Método override do contexto

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().ToTable("Project");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().HasKey(pre => pre.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().Property(pre => pre.Id).HasColumnName("id");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().Property(pre => pre.Name).HasColumnName("name");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().Property(pre => pre.Image).HasColumnName("image");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().Property(pre => pre.Why).HasColumnName("why");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().Property(pre => pre.What).HasColumnName("what");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().Property(pre => pre.WhatWillWeDo).HasColumnName("whatWillWeDo");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().Property(pre => pre.ProjStatus).HasColumnName("projStatus");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().Property(pre => pre.CourseId).HasColumnName("courseId");

            modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().ToTable("Course");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().HasKey(pre => pre.CourseId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().Property(pre => pre.CourseId).HasColumnName("id");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().Property(pre => pre.Name).HasColumnName("name");
}
```

Mesmo eu digitando o valor da chave estrangeira para um valor que já existe, o valor adicionado é o próximo valor do total de chaves, como um auto-incremento. Há algo que eu possa fazer? Minha função de tratamento também não está identificando quando envio um Id de Project que já existe.

Comment: Você está usando EntityFramework correto? Se sim, adicione informação sobre como você está fazendo essa lógica de inclusão e atualização no DbContext.

Comment: Acabei de atualizar com a classe de contexto.

Comment: esse `addProject` é um método que faz `Add` no `DbSet<Project>`? Se for, ele sempre vai criar um ID novo. Você precisa criar um método também para Update.

Comment: Coloquei o método na publicação agora. É correto ele criar um ID novo para o Project, mas teria alguma forma dele não criar um novo ID para o Course? Alguma forma de ignorar a tabela Course caso não seja adicionado nada? Minha tabela Course tem apenas Id e Name, e preciso incluí-la no Project da forma como ela está agora, com aquele "public Course Course { get; set; }". Quanto ao meu Update, ele funciona do mesmo modo do método adicionar.

Comment: @Tester aparentemente sua tabela de project não possui um relacionamento com a tabela course

Answer (score 0):

Altere sua classe Project deixando explícito o relacionamento entre as classes através da chave estrangeira:

```cs
public class Project
{
    //
    public Course Course { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Course")]
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
}
```

ou

```cs
public class Project
{
    //
    [ForeignKey("CourseId")]
    public Course Course { get; set; }

    public int CourseId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Fiz as alterações conforme o primeiro exemplo e criei uma nova migration seguida de um update-database, no entanto apesar  disso o Id da tabela Couse continua sendo auto-incrementado.

Comment: Talvez possa estar relacionado ao método override do contexto? adicionei na publicação.